# UIImagePickerController Edited Image - cropping some extra image on top

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using `UIImagePickerController` for profile image and the original image was[image: Original Image]

Now, I'm editing the image in `UIImagePickerController` as[image: Screenshot while edited/cropping in UIImagePickerController]

But, the `editedImage` frame from the `UIImagePickerController` is slightly different from the image frame what I cropped[image: The edited image from <code>UIImagePickerController</code>]

If you can compare the the images, during cropping and after cropping, there I cropped the image upto text "GIVE", but in the final image it has text "NEVER". Is there any properties I need to change in `UIImagePickerController` to get correct image as cropped or it is default from the OS itself?

Comment: Could you please update question with code!

Comment: We found this issue in work and found it to be an iOS bug, I don't have the bug link to hand.

Answer (score 2):

It is a known issue that has been there for a number of years now.

We dedicated a lot of time to investigating the issue in work but found even with a MVCE the issue occurs.

We also found a Radar link from iOS 8: https://openradar.appspot.com/18957593

We replicated the issue in iOS 9, 10, 11 and 12.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue and the only solution I found is to make your own crop functionality. Nothing else works.